Confusion regarding t statistics, or any hypothesis testing in this case
So I found an interesting example in one of the great books in statistics : "The Practice of Statistics for Business and Economics, by David S Moore". It has the following T-test examples.
Suppose that the overall U.S. average monthly expenditure for landline service is $49.
We test a null hypothesis that the average monthly landline expenditure in our community is equal to this amount. First, we state our hypothesis:
H_0 : population_mean = 40$
H_a : population_mean != 40$
Suppose that n = 8, x = 43.5, and s = 5.42. The t test statistic is
t = (43.5-49)/(5.42/(sqrt(8)) = −2.87
This gives p value for two tailed test to be approx 2*P(T ≥ −2.87) = 0.0241.
Now when we try to find the p value, where the alternative hypothesis is that "Monthly landline expenditure in our community is less than the population monthly expenditure."
i.e,
H_a : population_mean < 49$
H_0 : population_mean = 49$
This gives the same t statistics, and the P value is P(T ≥ −2.87) = 0.0120. So again we reject the null hypothesis in favour of the alternative hypothesis, and conclude that the monthly landline expenditure in our community is less then the population monthly expenditure.
My question is that this is the same P value we get when we want to test if the monthly landline expenditure in our community is greater than that of the population . So which one is correct? Is my population having lesser monthly landline expenditure or more.
The t statistics is the same, t = -2.87
P(T ≥ 2.87) = 0.0120 (due to symetry of the T-distribution?)
Sorry if this is incorrect and incredibly stupid, I am trying to learn statistics all by myself, using this gem of a textbook.

... this is the same P value we get when we want to test if the monthly landline expenditure in our community is greater than that of the population ... Not true, if your alternative is that x < pop and the p-value is $p$, then for the alternative that x > pop the p-value will be $1-p$.

Thanks for the response. But I have a followup confusion, assume that I didn't have access to the p, i.e x < pop case was not calculated. The t statistics would still be -2.87, so the p value for H_a : mean_pop > 49$ should still be P(T > 2.87) for the right tailed test. How would you use your T value for calculating the P.

If you know your hypothesis and the t-value (and df) then it is trivial to compute the p-value, you just plug the numbers in the formula. Where is the confusion?

Whence comes a pair of hypotheses that concern a $$40$ monthly cost when the question is about a $$49$ monthly cost??

@TheMightyBarbarian >"...so the p value for H_a : mean_pop > 49$ should still be P(T > 2.87)" No it should be P(T > -2.87) = 1- P(T > 2.87). The sign matters for directional hypotheses. You probably got confused because in the other direction you used the symmetry to calculate P(T < -2.87) as P(T > 2.87).
